# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo una duda al trabajar un proyecto de manera local (`wampserver`) todo me funciona de manera correcta, pero al subirlo a un **hosting** me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error.

> **PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean**

El parte del código es el siguiente:

```
//Mostrar informacion de usuario logueado
$iduser = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$sql ="SELECT u.Idusuario, a.NombreA FROM usuarios AS u INNER JOIN alumno AS A ON u.IdAlumno = a.IdAlumno
        WHERE u.Idusuario= '$iduser'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['cod']);
    $asignatura = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['nom']);
    $nota = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['nota']);
    $costo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['costo']);
    $vermaterias =" SELECT idasignaturas, codigoasignaturas,
                    nombreasignatura, nota , costo
            FROM asignaturas
            WHERE codigoasignaturas = '$codigo ' AND IdAlumno = '$iduser ' ";
    $existemateria = $conexion->query($vermaterias);
     $filas = $existemateria->num_rows;
    if ($filas>0) {
        echo "
            alert('La Asignatura ya existe');

            ";
    }else{
        $sqlmateria = "INSERT INTO asignaturas(
                codigoasignaturas,nombreasignatura,nota,costo,IdAlumno)
                VALUES('$codigo','$asignatura','$nota','$nota','$iduser')";
        $resultadomateria=$conexion->query($sqlmateria);
        if ($resultadomateria>0) {
            echo "
            alert('Registro Exitoso');

            ";
        }else{
            echo "
            alert('Error al Registrar');

            ";
        }
    }
}
$materias = " SELECT u.Idusuario, m.idasignaturas, m.codigoasignaturas,
            m.nombreasignatura, m.nota
            FROM usuarios AS u INNER JOIN asignaturas AS m ON u.Idusuario = m.IdAlumno
            WHERE u.Idusuario = '$iduser' ";
$resultadomaterias = $conexion->query($materias);
?>
```

Al momento de ejecutarse no me muestra nada en pantalla, pero al eliminar la linea:

`$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();`

Este ya funciona aunque con errores, si alguien me pudiera asesorar se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que la SQL no sea correcta o tenga algun problema que no retorne la ejecución y el valor de $resultado no sea un valor de objeto recurso correcto. Por el error que te esta retornando $resultado te estara retornando "false" en lugar del objeto de SQL

Antes de realizar:

```
$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
```

Deberias asegurarte que resultado es un puntero de recurso valido.

Este seria un ejemplo simple:

```
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if($resultado = $conexion->query($sql)){
    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
} else {
   printf("Error: %s\n", $conexion->error);
}
```

Tienes mas información en la ayuda de ejecución de [MySQLi fetch-assoc](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 1):

La consulta de sql esta retornando false, por eso el error, lo que pasa mas probable es en la seccion del sql donde estas asignando "apodos"

```
FROM usuarios AS u INNER JOIN alumno AS A
```

mas sin embargo estas utilizando "a" minuscula como apodo de tus tablas.